# Regular Expression for comma-delimited alphanumeric strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having problems creating a regular expression which will fix a valid string.

The string will be in the format:
any alpha-numerical character 3 to 5 times,
followed by a comma if there are more characters after
else its the end of the string

Example Strings:
A401,CR56,4U9Y,MO16,ECZGB,A7DC,9LN5,D52PU,UT95,YBPB0,2JWA,AAMW,KVG,6V8W,FWE

TRIR,J107,Q9X,FMFZ,VDAS,557,X7A,DRPB,S97O,8U62B,IN3I,H8MC,WS4C,U04KQ,X05O.

I have tried a few various expressions, but none which seem to match if I have an invalid entry. I know I could explode the string, and loop through the array, but trying to do this in just the one expression as it seems a pretty easy one, but can't quite figure it out.

Exmaple patterns:

```
echo preg_match("/^([A-Z0-9]{3,5})[,|$]{1,}/",$str);
echo preg_match("/((?<=[^|,])([A-Z0-9]{3,5}){1}(?=[,|$])){1,}/",$str);
```

and various variations on them, but I can't quite find the winning pattern, all help appreciated.

Cheers,
Psy

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think: 'I know, I’ll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: "And some people, when confronted with regular expressions, think "I know, I'll use a catchy quote that I remember". Now they have added nothing to the discussion." `   -- Tomalak   `

Comment: And a lot many people are eagerly waiting for a regex question to be asked on SO, that when a question is finally asked, there are 4-5 answers within a span of 40 seconds :)

Comment: Yup, thanks for all the solutions :)

Comment: I love RegEx, but when you don't need to use it, don't use it.  Just explode the string as you suggested.  You never gave us a reason not to explode it.  If you want to see if the data is valid, do your quality checks after you explode it.

Comment: Because even after exploding it I need to check every element is valid, by looping through and checking it against a reg-ex anyway, so It seemed (to me) to have less overhead to just run one reg-ex, rather than creating an array which is an exploded string, then looping the array, then comparing a reg-ex against each element. It may not have more overhead this way, but the reg-ex is also only one line of code vs the 8ish lines for exploding/looping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^[A-Z0-9]{3,5}(?:,[A-Z0-9]{3,5})*$/
```

Comment: A little unnecessarily redundant, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^([a-z0-9]{3,5},)*[a-z0-9]{3,5}$/
```

Comment: Funny how minds work differently: I had the same one as KennyTM, yet you choose to put the single `[a-z0-9]{3,5}` to the right (perfectly fine of course). +1 to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
(\w{3,5})[,.]?
```

Comment: "The string will be in the format: any alpha-numerical character 3 to 5 times, followed by a comma if there are more characters after else its the end of the string".
Therefore there'll be no     ___. 
There's no reason to overdo it.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
echo preg_match("/^([A-Z0-9]{3,5}(?:,|$))+/",$str);
```

Comment: `[,|$]` matches a comma, a vertical bar, or a dollar sign. Grouping is still `(?:...)` unless you work in Perl 6.

Comment: No, `[,|$]` matches either `,`, `|` or `$`. It does not match a comma OR the end of the string.

Comment: Missed that, I was just fixing the improperly nested paren. Didn't even notice the wrong brackets. Fixed.